# UML Class Diagram - questions on class diagram for user authentication

Tags: uml, class-diagram

I'm making a class diagram for user authentication ( register / log in ) i have some problem i'm facing:

1. is this how i indicate that a parameter is optional (phone number and username are optional)
2. should i make the log in / register a class or as i made it here a method?

[image]

Comment: Regarding your 2nd question: this opinion based as the e´requirements are unknown. Either remove it or explain the requirements in detail (as much as needed).

Answer (score 2):

Looks ok to me.

Some ideas:

The optional phone number and username are only optional as attributes. In your login operation they are mandatory. You should also specify a multiplicity `[0..1]` here. This is also possible for parameters of an operation.

Depending on your system `Login` could of course also be a class. It really depends on what your requirements are. Maybe you allow a login independent of a User.

Answer (score 2):

To specify that an attribute or a method parameter is optional, you can add `[0..1]`. In your diagram, you use three dots. It shall be two dots.

To specify that an attribute or a method parameter is mandatory, you don't have to add anything. You may remove `[1..1]` from your diagram.

`Login` is a verb, so I would expect it to be a method, not a class. But as far as UML is concerned, it allows you to have a class called `Login`.

By the way, standard primitive types in UML are not `string` and `int`, but `String` and `Integer`. If you prefer to use `int` and `string`, it would be good to define them as UML data types.