# uml - class diagram for log in and Registration

Tags: oop, uml, class-diagram

I made a class diagram for registration and login based on the answers I received in the question I asked.

link to the question:
[UML Class Diagram - questions on class diagram for user authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75203871/20850195)

Class diagram:
[image]
did i understand what i needed to do ? if it's correct do i need to add a list of users in the registration class or it's not needed?

---

Edit:
I replaced the image since I draw it on a paper

Comment: I'm really sorry :(. I'm learning how to use Lucidchart. I'm racing aginst time for my final project and im really i found out my professor is teaching us misleading information and he didnt use any editor and made us do the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to express that a registration creates a user, you sould use a create dependency: a dashed arrow line with an open arrow head with `«Create»` (the guillemets are part of the syntax). Dependencies shall not have multiplicities.

I cannot tell about the list. If a registration is for temporary transaction objects, it’s ok like this.  But probably, you may want to have a repository of users. This would be a class that sores the users and retrieve them by user id, of for selection criteria. This is no longer UML but domain design.

Answer (score 0):

Supposed the `Registration` class is responsible for the registered users it would likely have a list of those. Either you add an (likely private) attribute or you replace this arrow (which is not an UML arrow) by an association. Put a `*` (top of the connector) and the role `-users` (below) to the left and a `1` to the right.

Then you probably need a couple of operations like `userNamedLike(string):[User]` to return a list of users with a similar name. The `Login` operation will probably need the user name (as string) and a password. So the latter should be kept in `User` (as `encryptedPassword:string`. The meaning of the `registerStatus` (start attributes and operations with lower char and only class names with upper) is clear as dumpling broth (at least to me).